# Wrap records into a <p> tag in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So I have a table containing fields `description` and `short_description`. I imported these values from a different system.

Now I'd need to know how to wrap these description texts into a `<p>` tag.

The records are always always single-paragraph, so no need for the logic for multiple `<p>`'s for each two linebreaks.

What I want to do is go through each record, and add `"<p>"` to the beginning, and `"</p>"` to the end of both of these columns. However, after some googling I didn't find out a way to include the original value in the new value for `SET` in `UPDATE`.

How would that work? Or is there a better way?

Comment: [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) or [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [`concatenate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) the strings together:

```
update my_table
   set my_column = concat('<p>', my_column, '</p>')
```

`concat` returns null if any argument is null, so if `my_column` has no value you won't end up with `<p></p>`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
UPDATE 
   tableName
SET
   description  = CONCAT('<p>', description , '</p>'),
   short_description  = CONCAT('<p>', short_description , '</p>')
WHERE ..........
```